# String showing dot sequence after some characters in android

Tags: android, string

I am hitting a particular URL and getting some response from it. I am storing the response into a string. But my string stores about 3500 characters and then shows ... . How can I make it to store all the response data into the String? Please note that response is a JSON.

Comment: You should be able to get a String of length Integer.MAX_VALUE (always 2147483647 (2^31 - 1) by the Java specification, the maximum size of an array, which the String class uses for internal storage) or half your maximum heap size (since each character is two bytes), whichever is smaller.

Comment: Which XML? There is no xml. I am hitting a URL and getting the response in string and checking that String @Waqas

Comment: so there wont be a probable way out that's the max capacity of the string

Comment: Any otherway to solve it

Comment: Are you sure of what you're saying ? I can't imagine where this limitation could take place (and moreover the "..." appending). What I can imagine, is that the Debugger in Eclipse **is** clipping big String when you try to view them...

Comment: Yea, logcat in particular has a 4K limit, according to another question I saw recently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are dealing with a large json, better use [JsonReader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html) . This way you wont have to worry about those dots, and the outofmemory exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Try to debug and have a proof by displaying your String.length() value... Is it really 3500 ?